# Best way to redirect when logged in

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

I'm looking to create an index page of example.com that shows a login form when an user first goes on the site. Then after logging in, example.com will show a main page of their content. What is the best practice of accomplishing this in Zend Framework?

Would it be?

```
//example.com
//if auth is false, show a login form

//else...
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if($auth->hasIdentity()) $loggedIn = true;

//show "Hello World"
```

So basically like "if you are signed in, echo "Hello World", else show login form". I'm trying to limit the amount of if, else statements and was wondering if this was the only way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try rendering different views: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.viewintegration.render

Not tried this myself, but:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
if (!$auth->hasIdentity()) {
    //login.phtml
    $this->render('login');
} else {
    //content.phtml
    $this->render('content');
}
```

Not sure if there's a way of doing that without the if-else, are they really that big a problem? Controller actions should be fairly simple as far as I know, so there shouldn't be a huge amount of nesting around this code, or cyclomatic complexity within an action function?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear in my question. I wasn't trying to redirect them to another page. I want everyone on example.com - when a user who hasn't logged in yet, they will see a login form. If they have logged in, it will show "Hello World" for example. Is the best to just go if (//has identity) {show login form} else echo "Hello world"?

Comment: The reason why I don't want to do the if else is because what if I have a large amoung of info in content once they logged in?

Comment: instead of render i would use the redirector helper. same as above but replace the $this->render with        $this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl('/dashboard');

Comment: James: I already suggested a redirect but michael wants the login/content on the same page.

michael: surely most of that(html at least) will be in the view if it is static? If it's not then the controller action will just pass it on to the view from the model? I wouldn't fill your controller action with business logic or content personally.

If you really have to have it in the controller, you can always put it in another function.

Comment: the business logic will be in the view so the render('content') idea is great. I was just wondering if that was the best practice or how else do people do it without a really long if-else statement